# Update query not working with eval() funtion and parametes in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

In my project i'm using Orientdb, some problem in update query.

```
int amt = 100;
int recordsUpdated = db.command(new OCommandSQL("update A set id = eval('id - "+ amt +"') where eval('id - "+amt+"') > 0")).execute();
```

this is working fine. but,

```
int recordsUpdated = db.command(new OCommandSQL("update A set id = eval('id - ?') where eval('id - ?') > 0")).execute(100,100);
```

or

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put("amt", "100");
int recordsUpdated = db.command(new OCommandSQL("update A set id = eval('id - :amt') where eval('id - :amt') > 0")).execute(params);
```

is not working.
please help me to make work.

Answer (score 2):

Substitution of variables doesn't work everywhere in the SQL, specially inside strings. You could concat the value like in 1st example or trying using context variables, like:

```
OCommandSQL cmd = new OCommandSQL("update A set id = eval('id - $id') where eval('id - $id') > 0");
cmd.getContext().setVariable( "id", 100 );
int recordsUpdated = db.command(cmd).execute();
```